# What is the meaning of Domestic Exchange Rate here?

Tags: options, option-pricing, fx, valuation, quanto

So I have the following formula for the Pricing of a Quanto Option (see image below).

While I understand this formula pretty well, I am not sure what is referred to as "domestic exchange rate" (can be seen in the two last lines of the picture).

Indeed, does domestic exchange rate mean domestic/foreign, or foreign/domestic ?

In other words, if my currency is USD and the foreign currency is JPY, to calculate the volatility of the domestic exchange rate, should I look at USD/JPY, or should I look at JPY/USD ?

[image: Pricing formula of a Quanto Option]

Comment: The lognormal volatility of the usd/Jpy is the same as the lognormal volatility of the jpy/usd, because log (1/x) = - log x.

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot ! I hadn't thought about explaining it that way.